# how to change div color when an even "mouseover " has been trigged on that same div? pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var changeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("run")[0];

function changeColor(style) {

  var colors = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    style.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    break;
  }
}

changeDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  changeColor(this);
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="run">

    e3reerghdhf </b>

    djdhfdgfdgdhhghgd
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to change to one color and I want to hover over the div and change its color, everytime I hover or (mouseover). I thought that maybe i had to use windowSessionStorage to hold the index and change its value if the event is triggered.

Comment: What do you want to happen? You want the color to change only while hovering and then go back?

Comment: No change color to maybe blue and it I hover it again it should change to a new color. and again and again with returning to the original css color

Comment: What is that random `<\b>` tag doing in your html?!

Comment: Does it need to return to the original background color?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the variables in js, like so:

```js
var changeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("run")[0];

var colors = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
var i = 0;

function changeColor(style) {

  style.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  if (i < colors.length - 1) {
    i++
  }
  else {
    i = 0;
  }

}

changeDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  changeColor(this);
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="run">

    e3reerghdhf </b>

    djdhfdgfdgdhhghgd
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think your the only one who actually read the question. Thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can definetly implement that behaviour using Javascript, but why would you want to implement something that can easilly be done using a single line of basic CSS ?</s>

`.run:hover{ background-color:red;`}

EDIT: 
Change color on each rollover, using list of colors. 
You can use the array and a index pointer, and increment the pointer each time the event is triggered:

https://jsfiddle.net/ydrr0xn8/

```js
var changeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("run")[0];

changeDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  var index = colors.indexOf(changeDiv.style.backgroundColor) + 1;
  if (index >= colors.length || index === -1) index = 0;
  changeDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="run">ff</div>
```

Comment: Because he wants a different color every time?

Comment: @colxi, probably he needs 3 different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that progresses through different background colors **and** resets to the original background when not being hovered.

```js
function colorChange( el, colors ) {
  
  var i         = 0,
      baseColor = el.style.backgroundColor;  

  el.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = colors[ i++ % colors.length ];
  } );

  el.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = baseColor;
  } );
    
}
var colors = [ 'red', 'blue', 'yellow' ];
var p      = document.querySelector( 'p' );

colorChange( p, colors );
```

```html
<p>Hello world!</p>
```